# How to get Horizontal calendar with monthly view in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to achieve horizontal calendar with monthly view in Flutter as below,
[image]

Please let me know flutter library or package which I can use to achieve the same.

Regards,
Darshil Shah

Answer (score 0):

We are using `table_calendar` in our projects as it is highly customizable: https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar